# jQuery Autocomplete json search results not found

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery UI 1.10.3 and jQuery 1.10.2 versions for autocomplete a text box. 
I'm getting suggestions from remote site which return results when i check dev tools.

There haven't show any js errors or warnings. but it shows a label "No search results." even ajax returnresults. this is my code

```
  var street = $('#txtstreet')
                       street.autocomplete({
                       source: function(request, response) {
                           $.ajax({
                               url: 'https://myurlhere.com',
                               data: {
                                   street: request.term
                               },
                               dataType: "json",
                               success: response
                           });
                       },
                       minLength: 2
                   });
```

results json

[image]

Label shows before textbox

[image]

**I need to show json label value as a suggetions** Anyone know how to fix this issue, Thanks a lot

Comment: you may take a look  to [ajax-jquery-autocomplete-with-json-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493250/ajax-jquery-autocomplete-with-json-data)

Comment: @gaetanoM i tired that in success event i return that label value, the label values are correctly passing but still shows no results message without showing results
 success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function(v,i){
                    var text = v.label;
     alert(text);
                    if ( text && ( !request.term) ){
                        return {
                                label: v.label,
                                value: v.label
                               };
                    }
                }));
            }